# Scala - how to get a list element

Tags: list, scala, printing

I'm trying to get element from a list:

```
data =List(("2001",13.1),("2009",3.1),("2004",24.0),("2011",1.11))
```

Any help? Task is to print separatly Strings and numbers like:

```
print(x._1+" "+x._2)
```

but this is not working.

Comment: It's not Homework I've did it for myself from last semester exam. Well but maybe in someway you could interprete it as homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> val data =List(("2001",13.1),("2009",3.1),("2004",24.0),("2011",1.11))
data: List[(java.lang.String, Double)] = List((2001,13.1), (2009,3.1), (2004,24.0), (2011,1.11))

scala> data.foreach(x => println(x._1+" "+x._2))
2001 13.1
2009 3.1
2004 24.0
2011 1.11
```

Comment: O god, forgive me for forgeting of foreach ... Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6):

One good practice with functional programming is to do as much as possible with side-effect-free transformations of immutable objects.

What that means (in this case) is that you can convert the list of tuples to a list of strings, then limit your side-effect (the `println`) to a single step at the very end.

```
val data = List(("2001",13.1),("2009",3.1),("2004",24.0),("2011",1.11))
val lines = data map { case(a,b) => a + " " + b.toString }
println(lines mkString "\n")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
val list = List(("2001",13.1),("2009",3.1),("2004",24.0),("2011",1.11))
println(list map (_.productIterator mkString " ") mkString "\n")

2001 13.1
2009 3.1
2004 24.0
2011 1.11
```

Comment: Loving that `productIterator`, 11/10 kudos points for scalability :)

Comment: But the question is why is no mkString on Product itself?

Comment: I have many questions of this kind, Landei. Maybe I make a list someday and send them to some Scala mailing list. Also, why is mkString not called `join` which seems to be a sort-of-standard?

Comment: Once upon a time there was a long discussion on the mailing list about `mkString`, with a lot of different name proposals. As there was no clear favorite, the compatibility card won the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would use pattern matching which yields a programming pattern that scales better for larger tuples and more complex elements:

`data.foreach { case (b,c) => println(b + " " + c) }`

Answer (score 0):

for the Strings, use

```
List((1,"aoeu")).foreach(((_:Tuple2[String,_])._1) andThen print)
```

for the numbers, use

```
List(("aoeu",13.0)).foreach(((_:Tuple2[_,Double])._2) andThen print)
```

Comment: `((_:Tuple2[String,_])._1) andThen print` is better written as `x => print(x._1)`, or even `case (a,b) => print a`.  Do please let the type inferencer do all the work for you, this ain't Java!